# Working on selected rows without iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a data frame with 2 columns "series1" and "series2", I want to find the first index when a value (from series1) is greater than some threshold (in series2). I'm not sure how else to design the algorithm than iterating through series1 and find for each iteration min index.

Having 50M rows, it takes days to compute. Is there perhaps a different approach that I'm not seeing?

```py
def pandas_version(df: pd.DataFrame, signal_series: pd.Series, threshold_max, threshold_min):
    results = []
    series1 = df[df.columns[0]]
    series2 = df[df.columns[1]]
    
    # select only values of interest
    selection = signal_series[signal_series >= threshold_max]    
    series1 = series1.loc[selection.index]
    series2 = series2.loc[selection.index[0]:]

    for idx_dt, val in zip(series1.index, series1):
        window_series2 = series2.loc[idx_dt:]
        results.append(window_series2[window_series2 > val + threshold_min].index.min())          

    return pd.Series(results, index=selection.index, copy=False)

s1 = [i for i in range(10)]
s2 = [2*i for i in range(10)]
signal=s1 # or sth else
df = pd.DataFrame({"series1": s1, "series2": s2})
signal_series = pd.Series(signal)

pandas_version(df, signal_series, 3, 2)
```

Output:

```
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of `df` (for example, using `df.head().to_dict()`) along with your expected output.

Comment: `print(df.head().to_dict())`

Comment: All the operations you have performed have corresponding vectorized form which applies to the dataframe directly. Explore different dataframe functions @trytt

Comment: @Vishnudev do you mean `.apply`? I checked the docs multiple times without success. Can you recommend some?

Comment: I can't unless you give me some example input and expected output with steps.

Comment: @Vishnudev thansk for your time. I've updated the question with the output and the inputs.